# How to run Python from PHP using ksweb+ app on Android?

Tags: php, python, localhost, exec, shell-exec

I run PHP, MySQL using ksweb+ app on my Android phone (I have no PC) with lighttpd or nginx or apache server. I want to run Python from localhost using PHP exec or shell_exec function. I already tried below script:

test.php file:

```
    if(function_exists('exec')) {
        echo "exec is enabled<br /><br />";
    }

    $response = exec("python test.py"); // and with shell_exec
//  $response = exec("python /sdcard/Python/test.py"); // also tried this and with shell_exec
//  $response = exec("/usr/bin/python3 /sdcard/Python/test.py"); // also tried this and with shell_exec
//  $response = exec("/usr/bin/python /sdcard/Python/test.py"); // also this one and with shell_exec

    var_dump($response);
?>
```

test.py file like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

print("Hello World!");
```

If I run test.php every time it's display:

```
exec is enabled

 NULL
```

But if I run **localhost** using **termux** (like: `$php -S 127.0.0.1:8080 -t /sdcard/Python/`) and test again test.php from localhost (**http://localhost:8080/test.php**) then it's working good and display `"Hello World!"`. Also work if I run **test.py from SL4A app**.

Finally I understand that termux have Python (on /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin folder). But ksweb+ haven't. For that I can't exec Python from PHP.

So my question is:

> 1. I can install Python on /sdcard/Python folder or /data/data/com.ksweb folder by termux or another way? How can I do that?
> 2. or How can I use exec/shell_exec from ksweb+ localhost with PHP?
> 3. or there are any way to migrate or link sl4a with localhost for run Python from PHP?

I think you understand my problem. Please help me.

thank you.

Comment: Give (1) a try. Termux should have the `cp` command, I guess. Your ksweb environment might not have `python` in the path. If you can locate a valid path, you should call it by absolute path.

Comment: What you mean by **valid path**? thank you for your comment.